# Recovering corrupted tables

Tags: mysql, sql, recover

Our server was down by no reason and after we have recovered virtual machine disk and mounted it we realized that some MySQL tables are corrupted. Most of the tables are interconnected and this makes it important for us to recover every single corrupted table.

We have a big hurry, is there anyone to help us?

Comment: Which Mysql Version you are using ? : SELECT VERSION();  and which Table Engine you are using ? (MyISAM / InnoDB) ?

Comment: There are people that can help you in a hurry. And there are no guarantees it will work. And it will cost money.

Comment: What about backups ?

Comment: If you really need help, write me a email or call me